# Issue with sed / regex expression

Tags: regex, sed

Good morning. I am new to REGEX, so I'm bashing my way through it mildly successfully.

I need to remove a string of characters from a file, which follows a pattern. In RegExr, the string works fine, however when I run the command, it removes the pattern, but also *sometimes* removes the rest of the line.

What I need to do is remove the ", T = 3054626560" from the log file. The 3054..... varies throughout the file.

My expression looks like this so far-
sed -i -r 's/(, T =).+?(([0-9]\w+))//g' logfile.log

Input data example-

```
    03/06/2020 10:28:59.885 (27044, T = 3054626560) [D] [INTERFACE] Response Str: {"Status":0}
    03/06/2020 10:29:04.490 (27044, T = 3054626560) [D] [INTERFACE] Parsed Cmd Str: {
       "ServerCmdRequest" : {
          "CmdId" : 529
       }
    }
    03/06/2020 10:29:04.492 (27044, T = 3054626560) [D] [INTERFACE] Response Str: {"ResponseData":{"NeedAuthList":[{"dataSourceName":"UA_SYSTEM_TABLES","index":0,"isSystemTableDB":true,"needAuthentication":false},{"dataSourceName":"ABC","index":1,"isSystemTableDB":false,"needAuthentication":false}]},"Status":0}
    03/06/2020 10:29:05.228 (27044, T = 3054626560) [D] [INTERFACE] Parsed Cmd Str: {
       "ServerCmdRequest" : {
          "CmdId" : 17,
          "CmdInputs" : {
             "isTestRun" : true
          },
          "IDList" : [ 63 ]
       }
    }
    03/06/2020 10:29:05.229 (27044, T = 3054626560) [D] [CELL ACC]  SCell Created: [0x7fe7b0046220]
    03/06/2020 10:29:05.231 (27044, T = 3054626560) [D] [CELL ACC]  SCell Destroyed: [0x7fe7b0046220]
    03/06/2020 10:29:05.232 (27044, T = 3054626560) [D] [INTERFACE] Response Str: {
       "Status" : 10121,
       "errorText" : "Process run results will be lost."
    }
```

Comment: Try `sed -i -r 's/, T = [0-9]+//g' logfile.log`

Comment: Did it work????

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sry, I did not saw you posted an answer here before me. I´ve deleted my answer. Feel free to post your answer

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following procedure, given your input file.

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/, T = [0-9][0-9]*//g'
```

You could output this to let's say temporary file and then back to your log file if you wish to rewrite the original file.

Sample output:

```
    03/06/2020 10:28:59.885 (27044) [D] [INTERFACE] Response Str: {"Status":0}
03/06/2020 10:29:04.490 (27044) [D] [INTERFACE] Parsed Cmd Str: {
   "ServerCmdRequest" : {
      "CmdId" : 529
   }
}
03/06/2020 10:29:04.492 (27044) [D] [INTERFACE] Response Str: {"ResponseData":{"NeedAuthList":[{"dataSourceName":"UA_SYSTEM_TABLES","index":0,"isSystemTableDB":true,"needAuthentication":false},{"dataSourceName":"ABC","index":1,"isSystemTableDB":false,"needAuthentication":false}]},"Status":0}
03/06/2020 10:29:05.228 (27044) [D] [INTERFACE] Parsed Cmd Str: {
   "ServerCmdRequest" : {
      "CmdId" : 17,
      "CmdInputs" : {
         "isTestRun" : true
      },
      "IDList" : [ 63 ]
   }
}
03/06/2020 10:29:05.229 (27044) [D] [CELL ACC]  SCell Created: [0x7fe7b0046220]
03/06/2020 10:29:05.231 (27044) [D] [CELL ACC]  SCell Destroyed: [0x7fe7b0046220]
03/06/2020 10:29:05.232 (27044) [D] [INTERFACE] Response Str: {
   "Status" : 10121,
   "errorText" : "Process run results will be lost."
}
```